# write joined objects to file in an optimized fashion

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two R data frames. For example, orders and customers. If I write them to file with `saveRDS()`, they take up a certain amount of space. If I join them, I'll end up with one big data frame. If I save that to file, the file is much larger than the initial two. However, no new data has actually been created. I think R is treating each row as completely unique and independent. If a customer has 10 orders, their info is just repeated 10 times instead of stored as a single entity. Is there a way to optimize this? Is the only option to just save the two tables and join them every time?

Comment: Please include the code you have to join and save the dataframes.

Comment: If you have a common id (let's say, customer_id), you can use `dplyr::full_join(orders, customers, by = customer_id)`. That would transform into one table and would probably make the file smaller.

Comment: Whats stopping you storing two dataframes separately and joins those when needed?